# Assuring multicast delegate execution list order in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, events, invocation

*After doing some reading I understand that handlers invocation order is the same order as subscribed but it is not guaranteed  .*

So lets say I have  :

```
public event MYDEl ev;
```

and subscribers do :

```
ev+=GetPaper;
ev+=Print;
ev+=EjectPaper;
```

What is the best practice mechanism of preserving +assuring the execution list order ?

Comment: Unless you have a custom event implementation that doesn't rely on Delegate.Combine, don't worry about it. If you're talking of subscribers on different threads, precisely what ordering guarantees do you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what if I need to execute event handlers in certain order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043317/what-if-i-need-to-execute-event-handlers-in-certain-order)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645478/order-of-event-handler-execution , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364115/prioritising-event-handlers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's a field-like event, it will use simple delegate combination as per [`Delegate.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30cyx32c.aspx), and that *is* guaranteed to preserve subscription order. From the docs for the return value:

> A new delegate with an invocation list that concatenates the invocation lists of a and b in that order.

*In general* for events, nothing is guaranteed - it's up to the implementation. Heck, it could ignore every subscription you ever make. In reality though, any sane implementation will preserve ordering.

EDIT: Sample of a mischievous event implementation:

```
public class BadEventPublisher
{
    public event EventHandler Evil
    {
        add { Console.WriteLine("Mwahahaha!"); }
        remove { }
    }

    protected virtual void OnEvil(EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Who cares? Subscriptions are ignored!");
    }
}
```

This is just like writing a property which (say) returns a random number from the getter and ignores the value in the setter. It's more of a theoretical problem than a real one.

Comment: Jon what do you mean _nothing is guaranteed_ ? can my invocation list be ignored ? can you please explain ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If you write a custom event handler, you can do whatever you like. I'll give an example.

Comment: Regarding your comment to Rob , I asked this question only yesterday ( in another topic)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748434/multicast-delegate-weird-behavior-in-c  and every answer I got is that the order is not guaranteed. that's why I wrote the first comment in my question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Right... except for Simon Bull's answer, which is the correct one. I'm adding a new answer myself with C# specification references.

Comment: Thank you for investigating the other question as well ! again  - Thank you.